# Pass value to subscriber with ko valueHasMutated

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have an external object doing a lot of processing outside my view model. I want to be able to send data from this object using a trigger.

Is it possible to pass data to a subscriber from a plain object using `valueHasMutated` ?

```
function obj(trigger) { 
  var self = this;
  self.notify = function (value) { 
     trigger.call(undefined,value);
  };
}

function vm() { 
  var self = this;
  self.flag = ko.observable();
  self.myobj = new obj(self.flag.valueHasMutated);
  self.flag.subscribe(function(value) { 
      console.debug("Caught trigger with value " + value);
  });
}

ko.applyBindings(new vm());

// trigger
ko.dataFor(document.body).myobj.notify("Working");
```

The trigger is poping but the value i'm getting is `undefined`.

I set up an example on [JSBIN here](http://jsbin.com/aWaQeTO/3/edit?js,console)

Appreciate any help with this.

**EDIT**
Looking at [the source](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/f80f37800045edd2bbdb2b3510d9dda9822dfe11/src/subscribables/observable.js#L26) i can see that `valueHasMutated` gets the "new value" but still cant make it work.

Comment: Why not change the value of flag directly: self.myobj = new obj(self.flag) ?

Comment: This was [surprisingly easy](http://jsbin.com/aWaQeTO/5/edit?js,console) ! ko voodo. post an answer and i'll accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, posting answer, change the value of flag directly: `self.myobj = new obj(self.flag)`